# Issue in retrieving the task list from AuthorizationManager (AzMan)

Tags: azman, authorizationmanager

I am using authorization Manager in one of my application and my requirement is to copy the AzMan store from one location to another location. My source location is Active directory and destination is xml and I have the path for both of these.

When I create an AzMan store and initialize with the source link to get a handle of object, the number of tasks in the source store application seems to include Tasks + Roles. Could anybody please point that whether is it a bug in AzMan or I am making some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

A Role Definition (as seen in the AzMan GUI, not the API) are actually a kind of Task Definition. You can distinguish them by checking the IAzTask.IsRoleDefinition property.

IAzRole is meant for Role Assignments as seen in the AzMan API.